# determining local time vs. server time on remote desktop/citrix in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, scheduled-tasks

my c# winforms application is running on remote desktop and citrix. Both ways show the users time at their local time not the servers time. Now in the app i use SchTasks.exe to create a task to be scheduled. the user enters for example 11:00 am on the applications schedule form. They expect the task to be run at 11 am their time. Unfortunately the task is scheduled 3 earlier at 8 am because the servers are located in California while the user is in Michigan. How can i detect actual server time in my application using only c# and adjust the scheduled time accordingly?

Comment: Does the server returns its local time or UTC?

Comment: @alexey its own time.

Comment: Well assuming it returns its local time, you can convert it to UTC, calculate the time offset (i.e. -5 or +8). Next, do the same with your client time to find offset. Now you can find total offset to manually convert client time to server time.